# "JACK server could not be started" when using Qjackctl

Tags: dbus, jack

I have a problem when I try to connect my guitar to my computer, via line input. **Audacity** works well, and I can record what I play on my guitar (selecting from `Preferences` from where to record to `default:line0`). But the problem is in **Qjackctl** :
at first when I click on `start` it shows this error:

[image: error 1]

after that when I click on `Cancel` it gives this error:

[image: error 2]

This is the log from the `messages` window:

```
10:30:37.368 Patchbay deactivated.
10:30:37.416 Statistics reset.
10:30:37.459 ALSA connection change.
10:30:37.497 D-BUS: Service is available (org.jackaudio.service aka jackdbus).
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
10:30:37.512 ALSA connection graph change.
10:30:44.060 D-BUS: JACK server could not be started. Sorry
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Sat Dec  1 10:30:43 2012: Starting jack server...
Sat Dec  1 10:30:43 2012: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: control device hw:0
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: control device hw:0
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : Method "RequestRelease" with signature "i" on interface "org.freedesktop.ReserveDevice1" doesn't exist
[0m
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...[0m
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Cannot initialize driver[0m
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1[0m
Sat Dec  1 10:30:44 2012: [1m[31mERROR: Failed to open server[0m
Sat Dec  1 10:30:45 2012: Saving settings to "/home/gevorg/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
10:31:11.438 Could not connect to JACK server as client. - Overall operation failed. - Unable to connect to server. Please check the messages window for more info.
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Now I can't understand what my problem is.

Comment: I tried the command lines: pulseaudio --kill jack_control start and I got a message: "DBus exception: org.jackaudio.Error.Generic: Failed to open server"
What could be the problem?

Comment: Came here looking for the answer to very similar question, but it turns out that my USB guitar-link cable was unplugged, and plugging it back in, ensured that this error doesn't pop.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this from the command line:

```
pulseaudio --kill  
jack_control  start
```

Then when your done do this:

```
jack_control exit  
pulseaudio --start
```

And sometimes jack wont die, so then do

Get jackd's PID:

```
ps -aux | grep jackd  
kill -9 jacksPID
```

Comment: sorry for late response, but when i try `jack_control strt` it brings error:
`--- start
DBus exception: org.jackaudio.Error.Generic: Failed to open server`

Comment: The issue with this is that pulseaudio aggressively restarts.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so so much. This is fairly useful in the context of running [Overtone](https://github.com/overtone/overtone/wiki/Installing-and-starting-jack) and [Chuck](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2007/05/using-ddr-dance-mat-as-musical.html)

Comment: geoh why did the error stop for you, did you change something in the above command? I'm stuck with the same issue when I try this solution.

Comment: `pasuspender qjackctl` suspends pulseaudio so that jack can be started

Answer (score 58):

None of these solved my problem. This did:
http://dpod.kakelbont.ca/2015/08/16/fixing-qjackctl

> 1. In a terminal start qjackctl:
>
>    ```
>    qjackctl
>    ```
> 2. Before you try to start it, click the Setup button in the GUI (right-hand side, middle).
>
>    [image]
> 3. On the setup GUI change *Input Device* and *Output Device* (middle, right-hand side) from *(default)* to *hw:PCH* (In the screenshot one
>      has been changed and the other has not).
>
>    [image]
> 4. Restart qJackCtl. You should now be able to successfully use the *Start* button.

Comment: You are my savior. I tried all the mess with killing pulseaudio and restarting jack_control - all in vain. But your solution worked!

Comment: You are my life savior!

Comment: This is the recommended method according to JackAudio.org [Option #4:](http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html)

Comment: worked when nothing else did

Comment: That works, but why? I used to have "default" as interface, instead of manually selecting the device. Now I need to explicitly give the device. On Gnome.

Answer (score 10):

I made it and solved:

```
sudo killall -9 jackdbus
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

This worked for me and is the only answer I've found that actually made sense according to the error messages `ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0`

Thank you again!

Answer (score 6):

I solved the error `d-bus jack server could not be started` by deleting

```
~/.config/rncbc.org/QjackCtl.conf
```

and restarting `qjackctl`. In my case, I had messed up the settings, and it was stored in this file.

Comment: Fixed it for me in Fedora.

Comment: This worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of relevant explanations here:

http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html

I have solved my problem after prefixing the server path with `pasuspend --` *and* choosing the appropriate Interface (upper right corner) to the right sound device in my system, by clicking the `>` symbol and choosing from the list.

Answer (score 2):

I used
`sudo killall -9 jackdbus`

Then
`sudo qjackctl`

That worked!  But i don't get any sound and can't get my ffado mixer to run after that.

Answer (score 1):

Running QJackCtl from commandline as root user fixed the issue for me.

```
sudo qjackctl
```

Comment: I run "sudo qjackctl" and my Ubuntu has frozen. Had to hard reset my pc.

Comment: Same issue, my Linux Mint PC completely frozen with this command. I had to CTRL+ALT+F1 `sudo pkill qjackctl`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. View audio cards

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

(view audio cards)

Step 2:

```
pulseaudio --kill
```

Step 3:

```
qjackctl
```

In GUI find Interface:[default] and choose relevant audio card

Press  play |>

Step 4:

Run process requiring jackd (in my case, sonic-pi) then, when you're all done...

Step 5:

```
pulseaudio --start
```

This is sort of a mashup of the previous answers, but it worked for me while none of the single answers did.  It helped me to read a little about the differences between pulseaudio and jackd.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Does not work on my bullseye debian. Same problem as in original question. Also tried pasuspender because I noticed with `ps -aux | grep pulseaudio` that pulseaudio still runs after step 2 - also failed. Is it possible, that in 2021 the whole thing works entirely different? jack and pulseaudio seem to be conflicting - and redudant. A 2021 update on how to get tools like Rosegarden to work would be highly appreciated.