# "Jack audio server could not be started" in QJackCtl

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dbus, jack

I have been trying to start the JACK audio server in **QJackCtl**, but I get the message:

```
DBUS: Jack server could not be started.
Sorry
```

So the symptoms of my problem are exactly the same as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224151/jack-server-could-not-be-started-when-using-qjackctl) or [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/557906/problem-starting-jack-server-jack-server-is-not-running-or-cannot-be-started). However, none of the solutions named in those questions answers worked for me:

- When I do `sudo qjackctl`, nothing changes at all.
- When I do

  ```
  pulseaudio --kill

  jack_control start
  ```

  I get:

  ```
  DBus exception: org.jackaudio.Error.Generic: Failed to open server
  ```

Any help would be highly appreciated as the existing answers couldn't help me. I am using **Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)**.

Here is the error log of **QJackCtl**:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: Starting jack server...
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
Sun Sep 27 22:17:50 2015: ERROR: Failed to open server
Sun Sep 27 22:17:51 2015: Saving settings to "/home/username/.config/jack/conf.xml" ...
```

Comment: did you look this: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/using-jack2-dbus-jack_control-start-gives-error-dbus-exception-org-jackaudio-error-4175501811/

Comment: I tried the hints on that website, but it doesn't help for me. I added the error log so you can see it.

Comment: I found something [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1637399) and was able to thereby remove the first error: `Cannot lock down 82274202 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)` by first doing `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd2`, then picking `Yes`, when asked about the realtime latency. Afterwards, I ran `sudo adduser <username> audio` and restarted, and the first error was gone. However, `ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...` still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has it worked before now? Try using Cadence from kx-studio. I had lots of headache trying to run Qjackctl. Discovered Cadence,  and bingo! Everything settled. First purge whatever jack you have before installing Cadence. 
Check here. http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Repositories

Can you check the log through Cadence? Is it same error? 
I did not document the steps I took then.

If you use pulseaudio, you may have to install pulseaudio-module-jack. Only use jack2

Comment: Ok, I just tried Cadence as you suggested, however, the problem still persists.

Comment: After playing with the settings of **Cadence**, I managed to get it working a couple of days later, however I cannot precisely reconstruct, which change did the trick.
Now it also works in **QJackCtl**.

Answer (score 2):

I get this error when I use "default" as the jack audio device. When I specifically select my hardware soundcard or outboard card from the drop-down window under setup in qjackctl, it starts without a problem.

Comment: @MadMike No this seems like a good answer, just a bit short...

Answer (score 2):

Switch input/output from default to your audio interface.  I'm not a linux wiz but a music producer dabbling in linux and this worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)